# How long was Jack Campbell in his alternate reality?

Tags: the-family-man

Jack Campbell is given a glimpse of an alternate life in The Family Man. It starts on Christmas day and ends sometime after that.

How many days did he live in the alternate reality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was discussed in a thread over at the [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0218967/board/thread/153813005). The responders intelligently noticed that a store announcement just before the "glimpse" has finished advertises Valentine's Day specials.

When he returns from the glimpse, it is Christmas Day. Therefore, it can be surmised that his glimpse lasted approximately six weeks (1 - 2 months).

Comment: I guess I would say 6 weeks is more like 1-2 months and not 2-3 (8-12 weeks).

Comment: You'd be right... Not sure what compelled me to write that. We'll gloss over the fact I used to be a Maths teacher!!